# Strange firefox page size issue (only ff)

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, vertical-scrolling

I am not sure how to best describe this issue.  I have tried troubleshooting it endlessly.  I can describe it by saying, "the pages scroll vertically for WAY longer then there is content on firefox.  This does not occur on every page and it does not occur on any other browser.

Of course that isnt very helpful.  I could post the html but I don't that will help because its clearly a problem of both html and css.  I think the easiest way to troubleshoot would be to post a link to a page with the problem.

So, I will do that now: [www.docutoss.com](http://docutoss.com/)

The sites just a small project of mine and i'm really stumped with this one last issue.

Answer (score 3):

You absolute positioning of DIV elements is causing this. When you position elements this way your leave a "hole", and that is what is causing the extra space.

Consider rendering your page using only floats.

Comment: If this is the case, why do these "holes" not appear in Chrome or IE 8?

Comment: Try this: remove the IDs topheader, navigationbox, left, middle, right, footer. You will see the scroll bar shorten as these DIV elements appear in their natural positions. On the other issue, chalk that up to browser differences.

Comment: You're correct. I'm playing around with the `display: none` rule in Firebug, and the scrollbar does indeed get shorter. Very bizarre. Also, he appears to be using _relative_ positioning, rather than absolute.

Comment: I've not seen this behavior before either. I really encourage you, though, to try your layout using just floats, unless you have a compelling reason to use positioning, which I view as unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

what doctype are you using?
Using incorrect doctypes in the past has proven to be a major problem across different browsers.